# How do I create a default avatar if the avatar file does not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, file-exists

I used paperclip to let users upload their avatars. Everything works fine.

I want to show a default image if the user didn't upload an avatar. I used this code in my view:

```
<%= 
    if File.exist?(user.avatar.url)
         image_tag user.avatar.url(:large)
    else
         image_tag "default-avatar.png"
    end
%>
```

but it doesn't show the default image.

I put the `default-avatar.png` in `app/assets/images/`.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I followed the instructions oldergod mentioned in comments, but still the uploaded avatars don't show up.

Comment: `image_tag "default-avatar.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally put it to work, using `user.avatar?` like this:

```
<%= 
   if user.avatar?
      image_tag user.avatar.url(:large)
   else
      image_tag "default-avatar.png"
   end
%>
```

I think the problem is that `File.exist?` needs a path, not a url or something.

Comment: [`File.exist?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-exist-3F) is a Ruby OS-level method, not a Rails command. It has no knowledge of URLs, only file paths.